# Temporarily pause a function when button is clicked

Tags: jquery, settimeout

I've been trying to work out how to do this and haven't really got anywhere. I need to pause the function below when a button is clicked, and start it again when clicked a second time.

```
var About = function(dom) {
    this.text_spans = $('li', dom);
    this.len = this.text_spans.length;
    this.index = 0;

    this.init();

}

$.extend(About.prototype, {
    interval: 2.5 * 1000,
    init: function() {
        var that = this;
        setTimeout(function() {
            that.text_spans.eq(that.index++ % that.len).removeClass('visible');
                that.text_spans.eq(that.index % that.len).addClass('visible');
            setTimeout(arguments.callee, that.interval);
        }, that.interval);
    }
});
```

The objective of this function is to hide a series of text (for example, in `li`'s) and and loop back round infinitely. When the button/link is clicked, the function will pause and stop changing the text.

I know it's something to do with `setTimeout()` and clearTimeout(), but I don't really understand the syntax or method to get this working. Can anyone help me to understand it? Thank you very much :)

Comment: Could you please share a demo on jsFiddle, it would make it easier for us to help you :)

Comment: Sure, sorry I forgot. Here's the link: http://jsfiddle.net/Xb5Xg/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/Xb5Xg/2/)):

```
$.extend(About.prototype, {
    interval: 2.5 * 1000,
    init: function () {
        var that = this;
        $('a.toggle').click(function(){
            var running = $(this).hasClass('running');
            $(this).toggleClass('running', !running);
            if (running){
                clearInterval(that.timer);
            } else {
                that.timer = setInterval(function () {
                    that.text_spans.eq(that.index++ % that.len).removeClass('visible');
                    that.text_spans.eq(that.index % that.len).addClass('visible');
                }, that.interval);
            }
        }).click(); // start timer
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<a class="toggle" href="#">Click me to pause function</a>
```